# Calculating conditional probabilities for values in a 70+GB file

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on calculating conditional probabilities for values that are stored in a `csv` file, which is 70+ GB in size. A sample dataset would be as follows:

```
 Question 1   Question 2
[   'a',         'b']    
[   'a',         'c'] 
[   'a',         'c']   
[   'd',         'e']    
[   'f',         'g']
```

There are hundreds of Millions of such records. I would like to calculate conditional probability for `Question 2`, given `Question 1`. In this example, the conditional probabilities would be as follows:

```
 Question 1    Question 2    Probs
[   'a',           'b']      0.33
[   'a',           'c']      0.66
[   'd',           'e']      1.00
[   'f',           'g']      1.00
```

I could ideally use the following code (which I had written for another similar purpose):

```
probs = IncorrectQuestions_df.groupby('Concept1').size().div(len(IncorrectQuestions_df))
IncorrectQuestions_probs = pd.DataFrame(IncorrectQuestions_df.groupby(['Question1', 'Question2'])
                                         .size()
                                         .div(len(IncorrectQuestions_df))
                                         .div(probs, axis=0, level=0)
                                         ,columns=['Probs'])
```

But the problem with this method is that it needs the entire `dataframe` in memory. Given a 70+ GB file, I don't have the luxury of keeping the file in memory, so I'm here looking for memory efficient alternatives for calculating conditional probabilities.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: You should strive to give an example that is abstracted away from your specific situation. Is there any reason why you need to provide, long, hard to decipher strings like `'5696d0248e0e0869c96357d3'` instead of `'a'`, `'b'` etc

Comment: Anyway, the naive solution would be to iterate over the csv line by line, keeping various counts, and then calculating the conditional probabilities from those counts. It will probably require a couple of passes. This assumes you have enough memory to keep track of these counts, for example, for every possible pair of questions. Thinking outloud, you could keep a sort *trie* structure of counts maybe, for space efficiency. But perhaps that is overkill.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Fixed the question, thanks for pointing out. @ passes on such a huge file would take a pretty long time. I am wondering if there's a more elegant solution...

Comment: How many unique question IDs are there? Right now it looks like 12 bytes represented in hex (so 24 bytes stored as string). Maybe there's fewer than 2^32 of them, so you could temporarily remap them to 32bit integers?

Comment: @DanMašek: I'd say there would be around 125,000 unique ids.

Comment: pandas [provides a way](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) to iterate through files chunk-by-chunk. that may work for you in this case. Of course, some of the caveats @juanpa.arrivillaga may still apply.

Comment: It would take a significant amount of time, but on modern machines with SSDs, it won't be intolerably long. @DanMašek suggestion is also worth considering. That would require a single pass to map them, though. And now that I think about it, you could do the counts in a single pass for sure.

Comment: @Patthebug Then I'd definitely remap, that's approx. 6x reduction in size of the data.

Comment: @DanMašek: Yes, that's a good idea. Let me try that out, and I'll report back.

Comment: @DanMašek indeed, I would remap either way.

Comment: Note, 125000 choose 2 is 7812437500 combinations of pairs of questions, if order doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, how many unique pairs of questions do you have? If you make each unique pair show up only once it will further reduce the size.